# Where to store information about point in console application?

Tags: c#

I need to create a struct storing four points. I wanted to create a `Point` variable, but it looks I can't use `System.Drawing` in console application. What should I use?

Comment: Add a reference to the `System.Drawing` assembly or create your own `Point` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  should  add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` and then add `using System.Drawing;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;  

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Point point =  new Point();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]